# Connecting two different widgets through a button

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt

I have tried connecting my main window and login together if the login is successful. i have imported the main window class. I am not fully sure how this works, but im getting an error. how could i fix this?

```
from MainWindow import Ui_MainMenu

...

    def get_value_from_user(self):
        Correct_details = False
        while Correct_details==False:
            inputusername=self.UsernameEdit.text()
            inputpassword=self.PasswordEdit.text()
            cur.execute("SELECT password FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
            password=str(cur.fetchone())
            password=password[2:-3]
            cur.execute("SELECT firstname FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
            FirstName=str(cur.fetchone())
            FirstName=FirstName[2:-3]
            cur.execute("SELECT surname FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
            Surname=str(cur.fetchone())
            Surname=Surname[2:-3]
            if str(password) == str(inputpassword):
                self.msgBox1 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information,'Successful', "Succesfully Logged in")
                self.msgBox1.show()
                Correct_details = True
            else:
                self.msgBox2 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, 'Warning', 
                    "The Username or Password you have entered is incorrect - Please try again (CASE SENSITIVE)")
                self.msgBox2.show()
                self.UsernameEdit.clear()
                self.PasswordEdit.clear()
                break

            self.msgBox1 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information,
                'Successful', "Succesfully Logged in")
            self.msgBox1.show()
            MainMenu= Ui_MainMenu(self)
            MainMenu.exec()
            Login.close()


    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Login", None))
        self.UsernameEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Login", "Username", None))
        self.PasswordEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Login", "Password", None))
        self.ExitButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Exit", None))
        self.LoginButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Login", None))
        self.LoginTitle.setText(_translate("Login", "Login", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">STATION</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">JEWELLERS </span></p></body></html>", None))


class Ui_MainMenu (object):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super (Ui_MainMenu, self).__init__ ()
        self.ui = Ui_MainMenu ()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Login = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Login()
    ui.setupUi(Login)
    Login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The formatting was wrong. You have a class declaration missing "class Something:" at top, I put "..." but please edit your post so clear in what class are these methods.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.